# upload pictures with a button click(browse)

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile, image-uploading

How can I upload pictures from application UI with a button click. I'm working with titanium classic project in Android platform. Actually, I need this for uploading question's as a image rather than text field. Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a too broad question. Add your code. Explain what you've already done.

Comment: I want to select an Image from phone gallery and import it into my app. As I'm new with titanium, can you have any help for that.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer refers to the clarification you made in your comment since I do not understand what you are trying to say with your question**

On Titanium you can get images from the gallery by using predefined methods. Have a look at [the documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Camera_and_Photo_Gallery_APIs-section-29004913_CameraandPhotoGalleryAPIs-Gallery). You should definitely check out the resources referring to the [camera](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Camera_and_Photo_Gallery_APIs-section-29004913_CameraandPhotoGalleryAPIs-Camera) as well since the code to access the gallery is of almost equal structure.

Comment: I'm developing online MCQ examination. Some question and answer need to address with image. I want to upload images for specific question/answer.